# How to crop 486 pixels from the bottom of each JPG image in the folder with ImageMagick?

Tags: windows, imagemagick, batch-processing, crop

How to crop 486 pixels from the bottom of each JPG image in the folder with ImageMagick?

The following command

```
magick -crop -0-486 *.jpg
```

says

```
magick.EXE: no images found for operation `-crop' at CLI arg 1 @ error/operation.c/CLIOption/524
magick.EXE: no image to apply a property "%w" @ warning/property.c/GetMagickPropertyLetter/2561.
magick.EXE: unknown image property "%w" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3499.
magick.EXE: no image to apply a property "%h" @ warning/property.c/GetMagickPropertyLetter/2449.
magick.EXE: unknown image property "%h" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3499.
magick.EXE: no image to apply a property "%m" @ warning/property.c/GetMagickPropertyLetter/2480.
magick.EXE: unknown image property "%m" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3499.
```

Please, give specific example, internet in controversal (various names like `mogrify`, `convert`, various commands etc). Also don't point to ImageMagick "Talmud". Need just a simple example.

OS is Windows, Magick is installed with `Chocolatey`.

Answer (score 3):

Please make a backup of your images before using the following commands.

The command for a single image is `convert` or if you have **ImageMagick** 7+, it is `magick`.

The command for multiple images is `mogrify`, or if you have **ImageMagick** 7+, it is `magick mogrify`.

The command you want is as follows and it will chop 486 pixels off the bottom of each image in the current directory:

```
magick mogrify -gravity south -chop x486 *.jpg
```

The main **ImageMagick** command command used to be called `convert` but there is a **Microsoft** tool with the same name that has caused confusion for years, so all the **ImageMagick** commands were prefixed with `magick`, followed by the old name. So,

```
animate ...
```

becomes:

```
magick animate ...
```

And

```
mogrify ...
```

becomes:

```
magick mogrify ...
```

In the case of `convert`, which is the most common usage, you can now use

```
magick convert ...
```

or simply

```
magick ...
```

where `convert` is implied.